# svds not working for some matrices - wrong result

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Here is my testing function:

```
            function diff = svdtester()

            y = rand(500,20);
            [U,S,V] = svd(y);

            %{
            y = sprand(500,20,.1);
            [U,S,V] = svds(y);
            %}

            diff_mat = y - U*S*V';
            diff = mean(abs(diff_mat(:)));

            end
```

There are two very similar parts: one finds the SVD of a random matrix, the other finds the SVD of a random sparse matrix.  Regardless of which one you choose to comment (right now the second one is commented-out), we compute the difference between the original matrix and the product of its SVD components and return that average absolute difference.

When using rand/svd, the typical return (mean error) value is around 8.8e-16, basically zero.  When using sprand/svds, the typical return values is around 0.07, which is fairly terrible considering the sparse matrix is 90% 0's to start with.

Am I misunderstanding how SVD should work for sparse matrices, or is something wrong with these functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the behavior of `svds` is a little bit different from `svd`. According to MATLAB's documentation:

> `[U,S,V] = svds(A,...)` returns three output arguments, and if `A` is `m`-by-`n`:
>
> `U` is `m`-by-`k` with orthonormal columns
>
> `S` is `k`-by-`k` diagonal
>
> `V` is `n`-by-`k` with orthonormal columns
>
> `U*S*V'` is the closest rank `k` approximation to `A`

In fact, usually `k` will be somethings about `6`, so you will get rather "rude" approximation. To get more exact approximation specify `k` to be `min(size(y))`:

```
[U, S, V] = svds(y, min(size(y)))
```

and you will get error of the same order of magnitude as in case of `svd`.

P.S. Also, MATLAB's documentations says:

> Note `svds` is best used to find a few singular values of a large, sparse matrix. To find all the singular values of such a matrix, `svd(full(A))` will usually perform better than `svds(A,min(size(A)))`.

Comment: WOW... and we were thinking all this time how it was possible that our matrix was rank 6.  I'll just say it: I feel dumb.  Thanks for saving us a lot of time.